# Rendering Dynamic clickable images on Actions on Google

Tags: actions-on-google, dialogflow-es, google-assistant-sdk

I am trying to build a Seat Reservation Assistant app which lets the user book seats using voice commands. How Can I render dynamic image layout of seats on the Assistant and get user selected seats to book them?

If not, Please suggest alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

The Assistant doesn't have the notion of a clickable map. Its UI controls are somewhat more limited since its focus is more on a voice-first UI that keeps choices more conversation-like.

So while you may present a seat map, rather than asking for a specific seat number, you may have built up a conversation asking for seat preferences and then showing an option. If the user asks for something else, you might ask why, or get their input on additional requests they have. If you really wanted a visual interface they could select, you might use something like a list or carousel that shows the seat position.